# How to submit Formik manually from parent Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

In Formik 1.5.8 version I used 'ref' to submit form outside Formik. In latest version I receive `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs`. I also tried use `forwardRef`.

I uploaded code to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-morning-x03hm?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: This might be helpful https://codesandbox.io/s/w6nj3zl2l7

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Everything looks like it's working fine

Comment: @kenodek Thank you friend. That's what I was looking for

Comment: @Vencovsky in my code I used Formik v1.5.8. If change version to latest it will not working)